# Dynamically get all combinations of all elements of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permutation

IMPORTANT:
You can only choose one element from each array.

I'm writing code that will let me test quiz permutations. Below is the current hardcoded way I return an array of all possible permutations.  I need to adapt this to be dynamic, as there will be more arrays added later.

I was thinking of a method that would accept an array of options, and return an array of permutations, but my brain breaks after the first loop.  Any help would be very appreciated.

```
options =
[
  [["Geek", "Chef", "Supporter", "Fashionista"]],
  [["0-1000", "1001-10000", "No limit"]],
  [["Many", "For One"]]
]


def test_gifts(options)
  options.each_with_index do |a,index|
   ....
  end
end
```

**HARDCODED WAY:**

```
character_types = ["Geek","Chef", "Supporter", "Fashionista"]
price_ranges    = ["0-1,000","1,001-10000","No limit"]
party_size      = ["Many", "For One"]


permutations = []
character_types.each do |type|
  price_ranges.each do |price|
    party_size.each do |party|
      permutations << [type, price, party]
    end    
  end
end
```

Which returns

```
[["Geek", "0-1,000", "Many"], ["Geek", "0-1,000", "For One"], ["Geek", "1,001-10000", "Many"], ["Geek", "1,001-10000", "For One"], ["Geek", "No limit", "Many"], ["Geek", "No limit", "For One"], ["Chef", "0-1,000", "Many"], ["Chef", "0-1,000", "For One"], ["Chef", "1,001-10000", "Many"], ["Chef", "1,001-10000", "For One"], ["Chef", "No limit", "Many"], ["Chef", "No limit", "For One"], ["Supporter", "0-1,000", "Many"], ["Supporter", "0-1,000", "For One"], ["Supporter", "1,001-10000", "Many"], ["Supporter", "1,001-10000", "For One"], ["Supporter", "No limit", "Many"], ["Supporter", "No limit", "For One"], ["Fashionista", "0-1,000", "Many"], ["Fashionista", "0-1,000", "For One"], ["Fashionista", "1,001-10000", "Many"], ["Fashionista", "1,001-10000", "For One"], ["Fashionista", "No limit", "Many"], ["Fashionista", "No limit", "For One"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-product) method for this:

```
character_types.product(price_ranges, party_size)
```

To handle unknown number of other arrays:

```
arrays_to_permute = [character_types, price_ranges, party_size]
first_array, *rest_of_arrays = arrays_to_permute
first_array.product(*rest_of_arrays)
```

Comment: I think you mean `product` where you have `permute`. (I'll delete this comment when you've seen it.)

Comment: You can also do this: `arrays_to_permute.delete.product(*arrays_to_permute)`. Best not to have 'permute' in the variable name, as this does not involve permutation. Combinations, yes; permutations, no.